# How can I extract text from different parts of a pdf and create an excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with thousands of pdfs that I want to read with python and extract the necessary information.

In order to read the pdf I used this code:

```
import xlsxwriter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from six import StringIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    str = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()

    return str.replace("\\n","\n")
```

The output of this function is the next one:

```
Subject ID
15006-1308

Report Date
16 Jul 2020

Sample Type Slide Deck
Site Lymph Node

GENE
PTEN
PTEN
GNAS
TP53

ALTERATION
loss
A328fs*16
R160C
T253N
```

The first part of the information can be stored with conditionals. For example:

```
lines = list(filter(bool,string.split('\n')))
#print(lines)
    
    custData = {}
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if 'Subject ID' in lines[i]:
            custData['Subjet'] = lines[i+1]
        elif 'Report Date' in lines[i]:
            custData['Report_Date'] = lines[i+1]
```

Then I can use pandas to make a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[custData])

df.to_excel (r'export_dataframe.xlsx', index = True, header=True)
```

My question is about the GENE and ALTERATION part of the text.
I wish to have this in the excel file, but I don't know how to do it because first the genes are shown and then the alterations.
What I would like to have in the excel file is something like this.

```
     PTEN      | GNAS   |    TP53
loss;A328fs*16 | R160C  |    T253N
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to know how to create a DF from the data? How consistent is the PDF format? Would it be possible to organise the data when it’s being parsed? If not, what is the format of the data in general?

Comment: Yes. The PDF format is consistent and always have the same structure. the only part that changes is in the piece of "genes and alterations". Each PDF has a mutation analysis of a given patient, so the alterations change. And yes, it's possible to organise the data. I just want and excel with information,the gene and its alteration. @AMC

Comment: _And yes, it’s possible to organise the data._ Then do that, right?

Comment: Currently the DataFrame created with pandas keeps the dictionary structure. It would be nice to display the patient's data first and then the mutated genes. @AMC

Comment: Can you share an example DF, or the contents of `custData` ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to store them in lists first:

```
lines = list(filter(bool, string.split('\n')))

custData = {}
genes, alts = [], []

for i in range(len(lines)):
    if 'Subject ID' in lines[i]:
        custData['Subjet'] = lines[i+1]
    elif 'Report Date' in lines[i]:
        custData['Report_Date'] = lines[i+1]

    elif "GENE" in lines[0:i] and "ALTERATION" not in lines[0:i+1]:
        genes.append(lines[i])

    elif "ALTERATION" in lines[0:i]:
        alts.append(lines[i])

for gene in genes:
    custData[gene] = "" #initialize a blank string to add to

for gene, alt in zip(genes, alts):
    custData[gene] = custData[gene] + ";" + alt
    custData[gene] = custData[gene].strip(";")
```